# Hover on text link to change image

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events

I'm working on a project and need to work out some simple jQuery for a text rollover that changes the image in the div behind it.

See the idea here - http://sharifabraham.com/projects/

I would like the image to fade in `on:hover` and fade out when the mouse leaves. Each link on the nav will show the first image of the project.

Make sense?

Is this possible with CSS even?

Comment: Using jQuery? definitely! Which elements do you want to have that effect?

Comment: hi..i want the image to change in the slider div. ie - the image that is first there when the page loads will be the div that holds each image that appears when any link is hovered upon.

Comment: I don't think it is possible with CSS alone, but definitely a piece of cake with jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an outline of what you could do. On hover, we create a new `img` that will hold the necessary image and append it to #slider. The new `img` needs absolute positioning to appear on top of the previous image (we need this for fading). When mouse leaves the link, we just remove the `img`.

Change your HTML like this (add the corresponding image's URL to a data- attribute):

```
<a class="hoverlink" data-img="../images/flinders_house.jpg" href="...
```

And some jQuery:

```
var $slider=$('#slider'); //we save the slider
var $defaultimage=$('img', $slider); //and the default image

//mouseenter for the link
$('#projects .hoverlink').hover(function () { 
  var filename=$(this).attr('data-img'); //we get the filename from data-img

  $('<img id="hoverimage" src="'+filename+'" alt="" />')
    .appendTo($slider).fadeIn(500); //append and fade in new image (#hoverimage)

  $defaultimage.fadeOut(500); //fade out default image
}, 
//mouseleave for the link
function () { 
  $('#hoverimage').fadeOut(500, function () { //fade out #hoverimage
    $(this).remove(); //when animation is done, remove it
  });

  $defaultimage.fadeIn(500); //meanwhile fade in original image
});
```

Also we need some CSS changes:

```
/* #hoverimage needs to appear on top of default image */
#slider { position: relative; }
#hoverimage { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 100; }
```

**NOTE**: I haven't taken into consideration the loading time for these quite big images, my code assumes they are already cached. You could either do some preloading, or only start the fading effects when the image has loaded (`.load()`). The latter is not reliable in Opera if I remember well.

Comment: hey dude....that pretty much did the trick - i guess i'll just have to add some easing to make it smooth? it's a wee bit buggy as is. what do you think?

Comment: aha i didn't see your edit before i posted the last comment...yeah i think preloading is the trick. but even so - the images fade out - but not in?

Comment: I guess the fading in occurs while the image is still loading :). That's why it might seem like as it is not fading in, you need to do something about this (if you need help with the preloading, ask another question). Adding some easing might be a good idea also. Let's say I just provided the Christmas tree, now you can decorate it :).

Comment: ha! yeah thanks a million man. i'll try and tackle the decoration myself. if i hit a snag i'll most definitely ask another question. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Hmz considering I understood corectly you want this:

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><h3><a href="ideas.html">IDEAS</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="projects.html">PROJECTS</a></h3></li>
    <li><h3><a href="studio.html">STUDIO</a></h3></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$("#nav").hover(function(){$('#slider').hide();}, function(){$('#slider').show()});
```

Comment: hey again. i didn't explain myself very well. sorry. the navigation i am looking to utilise is the <ul> in  #projects. when one hovers over one of the <li> items, the image in #slider changes. to start with the image of the first link is already visible but fades into another image when any other link is rolled over.

Comment: You want the image to change into another image based on the item you are hovering ?

Comment: Update your site or OP with the urls to the images and we'll fix.

Comment: Who told you `nav` is an invalid tag?? Have you seen the doctype?

Comment: it's a html5 tag, he's not building a html5 site. But I get your point. Updated.

Comment: Hm, so what do you need to do to build an HTML5 site? Setting the doctype (and using nav) seems enough for me.