# Hover on text to change image with fade

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events

I have a series of text links, which when rolled over, would cause a specific image link to fade in; that image would not fade/change to a different image until a different text link was rolled over.

I did find some basic script that does this, albeit without a fade affect when the image changes:

```
<script language="javascript">
function roll(img_name1, img_src1)
{
document[img_name1].src = img_src1;
}
</script>

<ul>
<li><a href="1.htm" onMouseOver="roll('poster', '1.png')">111</a>
<li><a href="2.htm" onMouseOver="roll('poster', '2.png')">222</a>
<li><a href="3.htm" onMouseOver="roll('poster', '2.png')">333</a>
</ul>

<br><br><br><br>

<p align="center"><img src="1.png" name="poster"></p>
```

A perfect example is http://sharifabraham.com/projects/, which I discovered in a similar post: [hover on text link to change image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590878/hover-on-text-link-to-change-image). I've tried to edit and use the code in both of the aforementioned links, but to no avail. Any insight on what to do is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem? Also where is the jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've dropped the inline JS code since it's not the prefered way.

I've added a data-attribute to the `li`s which contain the image to load.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul.image-switch li').mouseover(function() {
    var image_src = $(this).data('image');
    var img = $('.image-container img');
    if (img.attr('src') != image_src) { // only do the fade if other image is selected
      img.fadeOut('slow', function() { // fadeout the current image
        img.attr('src', img).fadeIn(); // load and fadein new image
      });
    }
  });
});

<ul class="image-switch">
  <li><a href="1.htm" data-image="1.png">111</a>
  <li><a href="2.htm" data-image="2.png">222</a>
  <li><a href="3.htm" data-image="2.png">333</a>
</ul>

<br><br><br><br>

<p align="center" class="image-container"><img src="1.png" name="poster"></p>
```

**EDIT**

Sorry made a type.

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yVcV3/1/

**EDIT 2**

http://jsfiddle.net/yVcV3/2/

Comment: Thanks for the help. The above code doesn't seem to work for me, however. The inital image shows up, but nothing happens on mouse over of the text.

Comment: It works. Sort of. Mousing over any of the links just fades in and out the image specified in the "image-container".

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery to fade the images

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/