# Finish getting hover-on-text-link-to-change-image

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am trying to get an image to appear on top of the other one when the user hovers over the text links I have been looking here and based the jQuery code based on it but need help getting it to work
[hover on text link to change image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590878/hover-on-text-link-to-change-image)

I have tried getting it to work here as well
http://jsfiddle.net/edgardo400/pDTvu/

The html

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
    <div style="height: 335px; width: 945px; border: 6px solid #d7c3a5;">
        <h1>
            Cat Poison Control
        </h1>
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/35px-Black_Cat-icon.png');">
                <a class="hoverlink" href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/cat-deshedding-tool" data-img="http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/desheddingtool493x335.jpg">
                    What Does a De-Shedding Tool Do?
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/35px-Himalayan_Cat-icon.png');">
                <a href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/cleaning-cat-ears">
                    Cleaning Cat Ears
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/35px-Orange_Tabby-icon.png');">
                <a href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/how-to-give-a-cat-a-bath">
                    How to Give a Cat a Bath (and Survive!)
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/35px-White_Kitty-icon.png');">
                <a href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/clipping-cat-claws">
                    How to Clip Your Cat's Nails
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100110163009/farmville/images/thumb/b/bb/Black_Cat-icon.png/35px-Black_Cat-icon.png');">
                <a href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/cat-grooming-tools">
                    The Five Essential Cat Grooming Tools
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="list-style-position: outside; list-style-image: url('http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/40px-Andean_Cat-icon.png');">
                <a href="http://www.catster.com/cat-health-care/cat-grooming">
                    Cat Grooming: A Primer on Keeping Kitty Clean
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="catslider">
             
            <img class="alignright size-full wp-image-34" style="position: relative;" title="aspca_poisoncontrol_hotline_feathered"
            src="http://anime.edgardoroldanonline.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/aspca_poisoncontrol_hotline_feathered.png" alt="aspca hotline"
            width="150" height="150" />
        </div>
        
    </div>
    <p>
        <button class="btn2">
            fade out
        </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

and the jQuery

```
jQuery(function(){
var $catslider=jQuery('#catslider'); //we save the slider
var $defaultimage=jQuery('img', $catslider); //and the default image

//mouseenter for the link
jQuery('#projects .hoverlink').hover(function () {

        function complete() {
          jQuery('#slider');
        }
  var filename=jQuery(this).attr('data-img'); //we get the filename from data-img

  jQuery('<img id="hoverimage" src="'+filename+'" alt="" />')
    .appendTo($catslider).fadeIn(500); //append and fade in new image (#hoverimage)

  $defaultimage.fadeOut(500); //fade out default image
},
//mouseleave for the link
function () {
  jQuery('#hoverimage').fadeOut(500, function () { //fade out #hoverimage
    $(this).remove(); //when animation is done, remove it
  });

  $defaultimage.fadeIn(500); //meanwhile fade in original image
});

    
    
});
```

I appreciate any and all assistance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do but try this code. This example will add the image the first time the user hovers caching it, then it will show hide the image every hover after that.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/leviputna/cQqGf/2/

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    $("#box1").delegate("a", "hover", function(event){
        var $img = $(this).parent("li").find('img');
        var image = $(this).attr('data-img');

        if( event.type === 'mouseenter' ) { 
            if($img.lenght){
                $img.show();
            }else{
                $(this).parent("li").append('<img id="theImg" src="' + image + '" />');
            }
        }else{
            if($img){
                $img.hide();
            } 
        }
    });
});​
</script>
```

Note: If your hover image moves the link position you will get a crazy flashing effect. You will need to add some css to make sure this is not a problem.

Comment: yes this is it thank you very much :D now I will just have to add some css to make the images appear where I want them to and done

Comment: ok so I have the same exact code in both the wordpress site and in jsfiddle but it does not seem to work in wordpress could css be messing with the effect if you dont mind could you take a look here http://testdomain.edgardoroldanonline.com/apple-power/

Comment: or here as well left only the necessary and even default theme but still no luck
http://anime.edgardoroldanonline.com/?page_id=31

Comment: never mind fixed it was trying everything out and it seems wordpress does not like any $ whatsoever so i had to replace those with jQuery

Comment: the version of jQuery that comes with WordPress automatically calls the jQuery.noConflict(); function, which gives control of the $ variable back to whichever library first implemented it. 

If you want to use the $ variable safely in WordPress safely do this when calling the jQuery ready() function.

jQuery(function ($) {
 /* You can safely use $ in this code block to reference jQuery */
});