# Image change on hover of different links

Tags: html, css, mousehover, onhover

I found this: [hover on text link to change image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590878/hover-on-text-link-to-change-image) which explains how to do this with jQuery.

Is there any way to do it without jQuery or javascript?

Can this be done with just html/css?

Comment: CSS declarations are only specific to that element and shouldn't be able to manipulate other elements on the page. You would need additional help from jQuery or Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you can do that with CSS it's going to be pretty messy.  Why not use jQuery or Javascript instead?

In jQuery, try using the [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) mouse event.

You'll probably start with something like this (psuedo-code):

```
$(".linkclass").hover(
  function () {
    $(.imageclass).css('background-image','image.jpg');
  },
  function () {
    $(.imageclass).css('background-image','image2.jpg');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS:

```
.myClass {
background-image:url(image1.jpg);
}

.myClass:hover {
background-image:url(image2.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Right, but that will only change the image by hovering over the myClass div layer. I want it to change when a specific link outside of the div is hovered over. Is that possible? According to Anthony about, it's not.

Comment: @user1190348 not with css alone and no script